# Why don't flash videos play after upgrading to Flash 10?

Tags: flash, video, flashplayer-10

Upgraded to Flash 10 today and now many flash videos aren't playing on a lot of sites, including a couple i've created. What's the fix?

**edit**
Let me clarify here. this question is intended to find the code change that is needed to allow users of all versions of flash, including the most recent release, to be able to see them.

Comment: This isn't an IT helpdesk. This question should be closed.

Comment: question wasn't asked clearly but appears to be programming related

Comment: Ah - I get it now. I thought he was having problems seeing videos in his browser. My bad

Comment: Well, he is having a problem seeing videos in his browser, and some of the videos are from his own site.  So he wants to know what to change to his site's pages that will detect Flash 10 correctly in all browsers, his included.  So it is a programming problem.

Comment: Levi, since you accepted an answer, I assume that you found one of those problems in the way your web pages detected the Flash Player version.  I'm curious what it was as part of exploration at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346794/not-detecting-flash-10-worlds-most-widespread-web-video-bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash APIs only provide the version number in String form, so the probable cause is scripts that pull a single character out of the version string, and see "1" instead of "10".  That, or scripts that naively check `(version==9)` instead of `(version>9)`.

Note: comparisons like `(version>9)` will work as expected in AS, even if `version` is a string like `"10"`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to version checking.

Make sure the sites can handle double digit version numbers correctly. Especially when using strings, "9" is larger than "10" in many implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with HS that this is likely due to websites using a Flash version sniffer that excludes your player. This has been a problem for me in the past. To check if this is the case for you I suggest you view the source of the page and search for the path to the swf file. This could be inside the object tag or within a line of javascript. I usually do a find for .swf and copy the whole path into the browser address line. If the video plays when you do this I suppose you could send an email to the site admin asking them to fix their swf embedding.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a product of FlashDetect script which checks the Flash version you have by looking at the first character before the '.' like this: y.charAt(y.indexOf('.')-1); so when it sees version 10.0 it thinks you have flash version 0.